# Help me with my studies please

Tags: teen, self-control

I live in this hopeless country called India. I was born around 2004, so around this time I've
finished *11th grade* and entering *12th grade*.

In India, people don't give a **damn** about your talents other than your academic results. Due to this covid-19 pandemic, my school has been conducting online classes where I spent most of the time doing other stuff(mostly video games and reading novels). After the annual exam results(just above fail grade), my parents were so flabbergasted and gave me a device where I could only study. I accepted this because this was the only means of controlling myself(I still play video games for 1 hour a day). I didn't want to end up in some cheap stake college(my aim was high this time). But there was this problem, I don't have an ***interest*** in studying. I don't have any other option either because if I don't . . . You know what I mean.

I just want help in concentrating on my studies without distractions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this has nothing to do with parenting.

Comment: While you have some very useful answers, this question is not within our site scope as per our [about] and [ask] pages.

Comment: Hey, it's just the education system. Even in america the education system is crap.... it's not your fault.

Answer (score 4):

Born in 2004 would make you 16 or 17. Its a difficult age to be. Part of growing up is growing away from your parents, and figuring out who you are and what kind of an adult you are going to be. But at the same time you can't just ignore your parents because what they are saying is going to be right, or at least good advice, pretty much of the time.

> [Its at times like this](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/54479-you-know-said-arthur-it-s-at-times-like-this-when) I really wish I'd listened to what my mother told me when I was young.
>
> Why, what did she say?
>
> I don't know, I didn't listen!

Here is [an article](https://www.vox.com/science-and-health/2018/1/15/16863374/willpower-overrated-self-control-psychology) summarising some of what we know about "willpower". The summary is: its an illusion. Studying more effectively doesn't depend on mustering your self control.

So here are some suggestions.

1. Enjoy what you are doing. OK, this isn't much use for you; you don't like studying. But, could you change the topic? I don't know about the Indian system, but have your parents chosen your exam subjects for you, and happened to pick ones that you really don't like? Is there an opportunity to switch to something that matches your talents and interests better?
2. Avoid distraction. You've already done this by getting a device that doesn't have lots of built-in distractions. Any other ways of getting rid of distraction?
3. Establish a routine. Can you make sure you allocate specific hours of the day to study? Is there a place you can go to study where you do nothing else (i.e. not your bedroom)?
4. Give yourself rewards for success. Decide you are going to write an essay, or do 10 maths problems, or whatever. Then go have a cookie or a quick game of something. (Personally I never found that worked, but other people report great success with it).
5. Commit to small goals. E.g. tell your parents "I'm now going to write that essay on Antidisestablishmentarianism", and then you can tell them "I've finished that essay".

Above all, don't think of this as a mountain you have to climb, because the more you think about the mountain the more demoralised you get. Instead think of it as just putting one foot in front of another, and keeping going.

Answer (score 1):

> In India, people don't give a damn about your talents other than your academic results

You say this, but do not even mention any exceptional talent you have. If you have any talent, you can look into avenues on how to grow that talent into something that can earn you a living. Whatever you do in life, strong academics will give you a strong foundation for you to build your life in this. Also consider your parents want you to be living an independent and comfortable life, and are worried if you'll be able to reach that. For all its flaws in teaching and evaluation, one thing schooling requires you to be able to do the things you do not like doing and be regular and consistent. These are things you'll have to do whatever you do in future.

> I didn't want to end up in some cheap stake college (my aim was high this time).

The future is a knowledge economy, and you sound like you realize that. You can refer to [learning how to learn](https://www.coursera.org/learn/learning-how-to-learn). This has helped me (even as an adult) with strategies to learn. Note that learning is never done, you'll always have to improve and may have to change careers through your working life. You'll have to figure out the intersection between your interests, your capabilities and what the market is willing to pay for.

> I don't have an interest in studying

This sounds like high stimulus and easy path of video games speaking. You need to time and place box your video games and entertainment.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with your life?
What are your goals?

If you have some idea where you want to be in ten years, even if you change it  along the way, it helps you get over the next hill.

You might consider *"What color is your Parachute?"* a book about career changes, that might be relevant for you. Think outside the box. If you create a successful business selling something, no one will care what scores you got on your tests. Another book you might look at is "*The Lean Startup.*"

You don't have to be an academic professional to be successful. YOU have to define success for your life.

The terrible thing about being 17 is, you have too many choices. The wonderful thing about being 17 is, you have many choices, and it's ok to make mistakes.

Peter Drucker, a famous business consultant said,

> "People who don't take risks generally make about two big mistakes a
> year. People who do take risks generally make about two big mistakes a
> year."

So you might as well take risks. Good luck!!